# Change Text ON/OFF Color to Switch Android

Tags: android, xml, switch-statement, selector

I have a custom selector to Thumb and Track `Switch`

### switch_thumb_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_rules_box_control" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_rules_box_control" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_rules_box_control" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bt_rules_box_control" />        
</selector>
```

### switch_track_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_rules_box_control" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_rules_box_control" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_rules_box_control" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_rules_box_control" />    
</selector>
```

I want to get this `Switch` like result and put text ON/OFF

[image: Switch]

My question is how can i change the color of the `ON / OFF` text without changing the thumb image? The color `ON / OFF` text is white and the image color of the thumb is same. It confuses the two colors

Comment: change the `TextView` color on event of button clicked.....

Comment: What is the way to do it? @BurhanuddinRashid

Answer (score 3):

You can set the text color to a color state list selector. Use the same states as before, but use android:color instead of android:drawable as the value for each state.
[Color StateList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

Notice that this resource goes in res/color, not res/drawable

**res/color/switch_text_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#00000000"  android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="#FFFFFFFF"  />        
</selector>
```

Comment: Is possible set the text color "ON / OFF" through list selector? I can set track and thumb state but set text color ON/OFF i don't know.

Comment: you would use android:state_checked, just like the track and thumb drawables.

Comment: Let me know a example please.